# "cannot open /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: no such file or directory" no matter what I try when encrypting swap file!

Tags: swap, ecryptfs

I tried every trick in the book and I still can not encrypt the swap file. I always get the error:

```
cannot open /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: No such file or directory
```

So far, I tried creating the CLEANEST swap file, that runs in `blkid` and is noted with UUID in `/etc/fstab`. `crypttab` has just the header and no `cryptswap1`. I'd check that UUID works by turning swap on and off, then I try to encrypt and I get the error mentioned above.

I tried editing `/etc/crypttab` to include UUID of previous swap. I also made sure that `/etc/fstab` is properly defined in `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1`. Running `swapoff`, then `swapon` and I get, again, the same error.

I try restarting the service as suggested in previous posts by first turning swap off then restart `/etc/init.d/cryptdisks start` and try to start again. No luck again.

When restarting the boot lasts longer than usual but the swap is off, and, AGAIN, no file is created.

Answer (score 2):

There is not much use of encrypted swap anyways, if you plan to really use it. If not and it is just for safety reason then try doing `sudo cryptdisks_start cryptswap1` after you make the clean swapfile setup. Remember the swapfile needs to be there too! UUID and such is not really important and usually just confuses the system when you reset swapfile.

If it fails, try rerunning the `sudo ecryptfs-setup-swap`, resetting swapfile again, then again `sudo cryptdisks_start cryptswap1`. Sometimes it fixes the issue.